# Delete data (but not structure) of a Postgres database with a SQL query?

Tags: postgresql

I'm using the Postico client which lets me write SQL queries for my Postgres database. I don't have terminal access.

While developing I frequently have to wipe all the data which is time consuming. Is there a command which can do this?

I tried this but I get a syntax error:

```
DELETE FROM *
WHERE *
```

Ive also tried `DELETE FROM tbl;` and `TRUNCATE TABLE;`

UPDATE: If I run this command:

```
SELECT table_name
  FROM information_schema.tables
 WHERE table_schema='public'
   AND table_type='BASE TABLE';
```

Then I have about 30 tables, so having to run any command 30 times is still quite time consuming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate a single TRUNCATE statement:

```
SELECT 'truncate table '||
          string_agg(format('%I.%I', table_schema, table_name), ',')||
          ' cascade restart identity;'
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema='public'
  AND table_type='BASE TABLE';
```

Then just copy and paste the generated statement to run it.

---

You can also use a DO block that uses dynamic SQL to run the TRUNCATE statement:

```
do
$$
declare
  l_sql text;
begin
  SELECT 'truncate table '
            ||string_agg(format('%I.%I', table_schema, table_name), ',')
            ||' cascade restart identity'
     into l_sql
  FROM information_schema.tables
  WHERE table_schema='public'
    AND table_type='BASE TABLE';

  execute l_sql;
end;
$$
;
```

By truncating all tables in a single statement, you don't need to worry about the order of truncating them.

Note that if you have many tables, you might need to increase `max_locks_per_transaction` for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is incorrect.  You would need to run:

```
DELETE FROM tablename
WHERE columnname = 'value';
```

Truncating is faster as it will drop all the data from the table straight away.  The syntax for that is:

```
TRUNCATE tablename;
```

Comment: Ive updated my question. I have about 30 tables so having to the command 30 times will be quite time consuming. Is there a single command which would work?

Answer (score 0):

There is no single command for that, you'd have to write a script that `TRUNCATE`s all tables in the right order (and don't forget to reset the sequences).

An alternative is to create such a script with `pg_dump`:

```sh
pg_dump -s --clean -f script.sql dbname
```

That script will drop and re-create all objects.